# Android Spinner click away from dropdown

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, spinner, android-spinner

If user clicks on spinner, the dropdown menu with items will show up, and onItemSelected listener is activated if one of items was selected, however, how can I detect, if user clicks away from dropdown menu?

Thanks

Comment: Let's say you have spinner with Planets, if you click on it, the dropdown menu will shows up with all of available items to choose (Mars, Earth, Pluto, etc. ) however, if you dont want to choose any of them, you will click away and spinner will automatically close his dropdown menu. What I want to know is, which listener is triggered once you click "away".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `onNothingSelected` method for that,

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    ...

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Add your code here 
    }
}
```

According to the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html#onNothingSelected%28android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E%29)

```
  onNothingSelected is a Callback method to be invoked when the selection disappears from this view. 
The selection can disappear for instance when touch is activated or when the adapter becomes empty.
```

if your spinner disappear for other reason except selecting the item then onNothingSelected will be called. So as it's name tells it is needed to find out when nothing is selected.